# (PQ)²=RSP, where P,Q,R,S are distinct single digit natural numbers, then R=?

Tags: arithmetic, cryptarithm

I have a problem I tried to solve, but couldn't because I don't know the method to solve it and I've never come across such problem.

Here's the problem.

$(PQ)²=RSP$

Where $P, Q, R, S$ are distinct single digit natural numbers, then $R=$?

We need to find out the value of $R$, and given option are

a) $1$

b) $2$

c) $3$

d) $4$

e) $5$

I've tried solving it by option with newly created equation as $Q^2=\frac{RS}{P}$ and taking values of $R$ from above options and other variables as distinct single digit numbers other than $R$, I've gone to a level after which I've got myself a lot confused and didn't know what to do. I think there is easier method to solve it which I don't know.

I'd appreciate if someone could give me a hand with this. Thanks in advance. :)

PS: The answer is c) $3$

Comment: Do PQ and RSP indicate concatenation?  You should say this.

Comment: I'm not sure. They haven't given any more information about it. But I'm presuming they mean multiplication. Like this - (P*Q)²=R*S*P

I could be wrong though. :\

Comment: Oh.  You don't seem to have realized this!  PQ does not mean P times Q, it means the number with first digit P and second digit Q.

Comment: Qiaochu: You're right, but it can be seen why he'd think multiplication is happening; joining two variables as concatenation is something you don't see very frequently.

Comment: @J. Mangaldan: Yeah man, got confused. All sorted out though.


@Qiaochu Yuan: Yes, you've proved it just now bud. Thanks a lot for clearing up things and answering it perfectly. :)

Comment: Retagged from "numerical-methods" (which this definitely isn't) to "arithmetic."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The steps are as follows.

- A square number can only end in $1, 4, 5, 6, 9$.  To prove this one uses [modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic).  So $P = 1, 4, 5, 6, 9$.
- $40^2 > 999$, so $P = 1$.
- Since $(PQ)^2$ ends in $1$, it follows that $Q = 1, 9$.
- Since $P \neq Q$, it follows that $Q = 9$.
- So the digits are $19^2 = 361$.

Comment: OMG, thanks for clearing this up. Yeah, I figured this by trial and error and by going with options. LOL, all this time I was thinking its a multiplication and never had a single strike in my mind about concatenation.

Thanks man for clearing it up! You made my day! :D

Answer (score 2):

Generalizing from decimal to arbitrary radix, a quick computer search seems to indicate  that there are only a handful of radices with such a unique solution. This leads to a proof of the following

**THEOREM** $\;$ If in radix $\rm M$ notation we have $\rm (PQ)^2 = RSP$ with $\rm P,Q,R,S$ distinct digits and this solution is unique in radix $\:\rm M \:$ then it is one of the following, where $\;\rm A = 10,\; B = 11, \:\ldots,\: I = 18 \;$.

$$\begin{array}{|r|r|r|} 
\hline
\rm M & \rm PQ & \rm RSP \\
\hline
6 & 15 & 321 \\
7 & 23 & 562 \\
8 & 17 & 341 \\
9 & 18 & 351 \\
10 & 19 & 361 \\
11 & \rm 1A & 371 \\
18 & \rm 1H & \rm 3E1 \\
19 & \rm 1\:I & \rm 3F1 \\
\end{array}$$

**Proof**: $\;$ The two general solutions listed below prove that all radices $\;\rm M > 26 \;$ have nonunique solution (except possibly $\rm M = 44\:$). The remaining small number of exceptional cases were verified by computer.

$\quad\quad\rm  (1\: M + M-1)^2 \;=\; \;\;\: 3\: M^2 + (M\;-\;\:4) M + 1, \quad\quad M > 7$

$\quad\quad\rm  (4\: M + M-2)^2 \;=\; 24\: M^2 + (M-20) M + 4, \quad\quad M>26,\;\; M \ne 44$

Comment: Nice conjecture.  But when M > 81 you can check that

93^2 = (9M+3)^2 = 81M^2 + 54M + 9 = (81)(54)9;

i.e., (M,P,Q,R,S) = (M,9,3,81,54) is a solution for all M >= 82.

Comment: @whuber: The conjecture is true - see the above proof.